# Can Composer treat binary dependencies in PATH?

Tags: php, composer-php

I know that [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) can determine `php`, `hhvm`, `ext-<name>` and some `lib-<name>` dependencies. Would the same possible over commands and binaries on `PATH`? Actually, for instance, I wrote scripts to ensure that [Tesseract OCR](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is present. It can be done with own Composer features?

Comment: Difficult, because it would depend on operating platform; and certainly wouldn't be easy to test for versions or to install them for you

Comment: Yep, versioning is impossible to handle. But I think that you can test presence in a way cross platform way, only using vanilla PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using a Composer hook, like `pre-install-cmd` or `pre-update-cmd`, which executes a PHP method. Here is my test:

`composer.json`

```
{
  "require": { "pimple/pimple": "*" },
  "autoload": { "psr-0": { "Acme\\": "src/" } }
  "scripts": {
    "pre-install-cmd": "Acme\\Composer\\Hooks::checkBinary",
    "pre-update-cmd": "Acme\\Composer\\Hooks::checkBinary"
  }
}
```

`src/Acme/Composer/Hooks.php`

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Composer;

use Composer\Script\Event;

class Hooks
{
    public static function checkBinary(Event $event) {
        $io = $event->getIO();
        $path = explode(':', getenv('PATH'));
        // do something with $path elements or anything else
        if ($somethingWentWrong) {
            // Throwing an Exception will cause Composer to stop processing.
            throw new \Exception('Check your PATH');
        } else {
            $io->write('checkBinary() completed.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After some research, I think this is the most cross-platform method.

Comment: Btw. composer hooks are only ran in the root package. If you add them to your lib, they have no effect!