# How to determine the vendor/bin directory of Composer in a library?

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there a reliable way to determine the local `vendor/bin` directory of an application from within a library? What I really want is the following:

I am writing a library that depends on a third library. This third library ships with a binary, that is installed in the local `vendor/bin` of the main application. My library needs to have the possibility to execute this binary. I could probably hack something using `__DIR__/../...../bin` but that feels not very good an is probably *not* reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bin` can be changed, two ways: [changing bin dir](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md#can-vendor-binaries-be-installed-somewhere-other-than-vendor-bin-)

Here is your solution: [Can Composer treat binary dependencies in PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035742/can-composer-treat-binary-dependencies-in-path)

Now you have the `path`. You will need to figure out how(where) to store that data.

Comment: Mmmm ... but that would require, that all binaries get installed into a directory that is configured in PATH. I have to think about this a little further. In any case thanks: i did not know, that you can change the bin dir.

Comment: Read the 2nd link again. In your composer.json you could have hook. In post install (for example) hook, you have variable `bin` witch holds the bin path. Also read when these scripts are called.